# Descriptive Build Variant names in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Is it possible to define descriptive names for build flavors/build types combinations to be shown in "Build Variant" pull down menu of the Android Studio?

E.g. "Release with productive API" instead of "prodRelease" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

> After you create and configure your product flavors, click Sync Now in
>   the notification bar. After the sync completes, Gradle automatically
>   creates build variants based on your build types and product flavors,
>   and names them according to <product-flavor><Build-Type>. For example,
>   if you created 'demo' and 'full' product flavors, and kept the default
>   'debug' and 'release' build types, Gradle creates the following build
>   variants:
>
> demoDebug 
>   demoRelease 
>   fullDebug 
>   fullRelease

According to documentation [ApplicationVariantImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/828374f6354fe11aff838fe6f496a4a10520b9aa/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/api/ApplicationVariantImpl.java) has method `getName` and `getDescription`, and both are computed. `getDescription` is implemented in [ApkVariantData](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/variant/ApkVariantData.java) class by the following code.

```
@Override
@NonNull
public String getDescription() {
    if (getVariantConfiguration().hasFlavors()) {
        return String.format("%s build for flavor %s",
                getCapitalizedBuildTypeName(),
                getFlavoredName(true));
    } else {
        return String.format("%s build", getCapitalizedBuildTypeName());
    }
}
```

Sources:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html